# Question about the number of units in the output layer for a function approximation neural network using Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, output

I am trying to implement a Dense neural network to approximate a given function y=0.9x^3 + 2x^2 + 12. I have created 50,000 samples that include x and the corresponding y values.
The first hidden layer must have 12 units, second hidden layer must have 8 units and the last one must have 4 units. This is what I have done so far to implement this structure:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add (Dense(12, input_shape = (50000,), activation = 'relu'))
model.add (Dense(8, activation = 'relu'))
model.add (Dense(4, activation = 'relu'))
model.add (Dense(50000, activation = 'linear'))
```

I specified 50,000 units for the output layer because I have 50,000 y values for each of my samples - is this correct for the number of units of the output layer?

Comment: You have 50,000 samples and each sample has 50,000 y values?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: You are computing a function which has one X as input and one Y as output. So both the input shape and output shape, are 1. I think you have made a mistake that each sample has 50000 y values. It's impossible with your function. You have 50000 samples, and each of them has 1 X and 1 y. So change input shape of first layer and neurons of last layer to 1.

Comment: Thank you @Kaveh, I made the necessary changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are computing a function which has one X as input and one Y as output:

*y=0.9x^3 + 2x^2 + 12*

So both the input shape and output shape, should be 1. I think you have made a mistake that each sample has 50000 y values. It's impossible with your function. You have 50000 samples, and each of them has 1 X and 1 y.

For example:

```
x = tf.random.uniform((50000,),dtype=tf.float32, minval=0, maxval=100)#random x values
y = tf.multiply(0.9,tf.pow(x,3)) + tf.multiply(2,tf.pow(x,2)) + 12   #y= 0.9x^3 + 2x^2 + 12
```

Then, changes to your proposed model should be like this:

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add (Dense(12, input_shape = (1,), activation = 'relu'))
model.add (Dense(8, activation = 'relu'))
model.add (Dense(4, activation = 'relu'))
model.add (Dense(1, activation = 'linear'))
```

Comment: Thanks Kaveh - it makes sense now.